# Looking for how to keep the value of a increment of loops as argument for buttons

Tags: python-3.x

I m trying to make a set of buttons :

- one per item on my list
- each one is using the same fonction
- the buttons have numbers
- thoses numbers are send to the fonction called by my fonction

The best option i found was creation a loop to make buttons, and it give them their numbers and command

my code below

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def print_row_number(value = int):
    print(value)

fen1 = Tk()
fen1.geometry("800x800")

##  V A R I A B L E S  ###
my_list = ['test!',"another test", 'thisis my last one']


###### C O D E ####

for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    button_left = tk.Button(master=fen1, text=f"boucle ligne {i+1} : {my_list[i]}, this button should print {i}", command=lambda: print_row_number((i)))
    button_left.grid(row= i, column=0)
    i=+1

fen1.mainloop()
```

on the buttons, the values are good, it says  1, 2, 3 but the buttons calls i afterwars and they all print 2

i tryed to switch to
`from value in my_list`

and use the index fonction of list, hoping this would solve it, but didnt change a thing

i also tryed to make a local variable, but its not one per loop so it didnt work either

Comment: Take a look at the recommended approach to adding extra argument to event handling as suggested in [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/extra-args.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work as per your expectations:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def print_row_number(value = int):
    print(value)

fen1 = Tk()
fen1.geometry("800x800")

##  V A R I A B L E S  ###
my_list = ['test!',"another test", 'thisis my last one']


###### C O D E ####

for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    button_left = tk.Button(master=fen1, text=f"boucle ligne {i+1} : {my_list[i]}, this button should print {i}", command=lambda j = i: print_row_number((j)))
    button_left.grid(row= i, column=0)
    i=+1

fen1.mainloop()
```

Passing arguments through lambda function did the trick.

```
command=lambda j = i: print_row_number((j)))
```

**Explanation:**
One of the possibilities of why your code wasn't working as expected is because, the arguments were not binding with the function. The above lambda expression binds the iterating value of "i" with the print_row_number function.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: this worked perfectly thanks !
i d like to understand better how this works tho. could you explain a bit ?